# goroutine soon blocked the http server when it was requested

Tags: http, go, block, goroutine

**goroutine sooblocked the http server when it was reqn uested**

The following code will soon be blocked

In a device management function, by visiting the http REST ful interface to determine whether the device is online, 30s access to 1000 devices, the current program is roughly as follows to see the number of goroutine is not very high, but soon the program will not Move, cpu, memory is not occupied too high

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func a() {
    b()
    //.....
}

var bb = 0

func b() {
    fmt.Printf("b:%d\n", bb)
    bb++
    resp, err := http.Get("http://www.baidu.com")
    if err == nil {
        resp.Body.Close()
    }
    //...
}
func c() {
    t := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 30)
    for {
        fmt.Printf("start time:%s\n", time.Now().Format("15:04:05"))
        bb = 0
        for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
            go a()
            if i%11 == 0 {
                time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 300)
                fmt.Printf("i:%d go:%d\n", i, runtime.NumGoroutine())
            }
        }
        <-t.C
        fmt.Printf("over time:%s\n", time.Now().Format("15:04:05"))
    }
}
func main() {
    go c()
    for {

    }
}
```

[block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Es2j.png)

The following code will not block，This is why, hope to give me some advice, thank you

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func a() {
    b()
}

var bb = 0

func b() {
    fmt.Printf("b:%d\n", bb)
    bb++
    resp, err := http.Get("http://www.baidu.com")
    if err == nil {
        resp.Body.Close()
    }

}

func main() {
    for {
        for {
        go b()
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10)
        fmt.Printf("go:%d\n", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    }
}
```

[no-block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkm7j.png)

Comment: You have a busy loop in your code. Don't do that.

Comment: What JimB said: Never ever do a `for {}`. Never. No arguing.

Comment: You also have a race condition on `bb`. And you can figure out where it's blocking by issuing a SIGQUIT to the process, which will [trigger a stack dump](https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#hdr-Default_behavior_of_signals_in_Go_programs).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no switching point.
the Go scheduler is non preemptive. (cooperative)
all goroutines must be cooperative of scheduling

```
func main() {
    go c()
    for {
        // it is not cooperative
    }
}
```

the Go scheduler can switch only at specific points. 
specific points is I/O, chan, Sleep, Gosched

try below code on block example

```
func main() {
    go c()
    for {
        runtime.Gosched() // or time.Sleep(any)
    }
}
```

I hope this would help you