# Can't run go web serve in goroutine on Linux (Mint)

Tags: linux, go

I am trying to start a web server inside my go application. When I run my code on Windows everything works as expected. The application runs it starts the web server and then waits. On linux it appears to do the same thing except I am unable to access the web server.

If I start the web server without using a goroutine the server works, it's only when I use a goroutine that it fails.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    // go startWebServer()  // This only works on Windows.
    // startWebServer()     // This works on both Windows and Linux.
    fmt.Println("Started web server...")
    for {}
}

func startWebServer() {
    fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./web"))
    http.Handle("/web/", http.StripPrefix("/web/", fileServer))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8101", nil))
}
```

I have a simple HTML file in my web folder, any valid HTML will do.

```
 <h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1>
```

Then I point the browser to http://127.0.0.1:8101/web/index.html

On Windows I get my page regardless of which method I use.

On Linux I can only get to my page if I DON'T use a goroutine.

Comment: Are both OS installed on the same system ?

Comment: The linux machine is virtual, running on the windows machine.

Comment: What happens on Linux with the goroutine? HTTP error? Timeout? Any console output from your app? Does the app continue running or does it exit?

Comment: Also note that your `for {}` will tie up one CPU core at 100% as long as the app is running. `select {}` is more friendly as it uses no resources.

Comment: Looks like it was the     for {} that was the problem. I changed it to select {} and it works on both Windows and Linux now. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46120712/goroutine-soon-blocked-the-http-server-when-it-was-requested, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624959/golang-http-server-blocks-when-starts-a-goroutine-of-infinite-loop,

Comment: Not sure what you're doing wrong, but if I uncomment the line "only works on windows" I get my test page just fine on linux.  Which version of go are you using on which OS?

Answer (score -1):

Actually that depends on the number cores available in the CPU. That's how go routines works. In your case running the same program on Windows provide all the cores available for your go routine to run.

But when you are running your program on virtual linux OS. It will limit to less number of resource.

To check that how many cores your program is using use GOMAXPROCS on both linux and windows separately.

```
package main

import (
    "runtime"
    "fmt"
)

func getGOMAXPROCS() int {
    return runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("GOMAXPROCS is %d\n", getGOMAXPROCS())
}
```

Working Code on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jEIrw-XhBap)

> GOMAXPROCS sets the maximum number of CPUs that can be executing
>   simultaneously and returns the previous setting. If n < 1, it does not
>   change the current setting. The number of logical CPUs on the local
>   machine can be queried with NumCPU. This call will go away when the
>   scheduler improves.

**Note:** Also do not use never ending loop even if you want to wait for go routine use `WaitGroups.`

Comment: Per the posted code, `main` won't exit until the app is killed. The last line in `main` is `for {}`. There is *no way* that "main exits before your go routine finish execution" with the given code in the question.

Comment: @Adrian Surely I have just read the comments and along with that if there is never ending for loop, the program will hang after sometime or if there are less cores used than it will hang within few minutes. Hence again my answer is correct what can be the reason behind. And you have also provided same reason in the comments.